# Groovy Spock How to Wire or Mock Spring Autowired Interface

Tags: spring, groovy, spock

I have a class like this

```
public abstract class JobProcessor {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    protected void startProcess() {
        MyThread myThread= (MyThread) applicationContext.getBean("myThread");
        myThread.setConversionObject(new MyObject());
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to write unit test for JobProcessor. JobProcessor is an abstract class.and it is autowired with ApplicationContext which is an interface.

My test is like this

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = JobProcessorApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:InjectionContext.xml")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@Import(UnitTestConfiguration)
class JobProcessorSpec extends Specification {
    class JobProcessorChild extends JobProcessor {

        @Override
        boolean processRequest() {
            return false
        }

        def "Should start process"() { 
            given: 
            def jobProcessorChild = new JobProcessorChild()
            when:
            jobProcessorChild.startProcess()
            then:
            noExceptionThrown()
        }
    }
}
```

My test always fails for nullpoint error of applicationContext
Can anyone please guide me how to write unit test properly here?

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should run without applicationContext being built. You have to replace it with a mock object which you will then pass into your object's constructor in the test.